# Checking if a website exists, returning false for google.com

Tags: php, curl

I'm using the following method to check if a website exists:

```
function urlExists($url = NULL) {  
    if ($url == NULL) return false;  
    $ch = curl_init($url);  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);  
    $data = curl_exec($ch);  
    $httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);  
    curl_close($ch);   
    if ($httpcode >= 200 && $httpcode < 300){  
        return true;  
    } else {  
        return false;  
    }  
}
```

It seems to return false for `google.com`, but not for `www.google.com`. Why?

Comment: Why not check the response and find out?

Comment: I think google.com redirects to www.google.com, and you are not checking for that.

Comment: your definition of *existence* is narrow

Comment: `CURL_FOLLOWLOCATION`

Comment: google.com likely returns a 301 or 302 status.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google has a page redirect. So use this option as well.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
```

If your link contains `https://` then use:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,false);
```